# Is there a way to count the number of iterations in a while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a really simple while loop that rolls a dice until it rolls a 6. I'm relatively new to python and not sure if there is a method that already exists that I can use to count the number of rolls it takes. The code I have is:

```
import random

mace_trans = 0
while mace_trans != 6:
    mace_trans = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(mace_trans)
```

Comment: The simple way is `i=0` outside the loop, and `i += 1` inside the loop.  There are tricky ways, but that will solve the problem.

Comment: Did you *try anything at all*?

Comment: Counting loop iterations is a trivial and introductory exercise in Python.  We expect you to search and find such support from existing resources.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a variable and increment it:

```py
import random

# Initialize it to 0
num_rolls = 0

mace_trans = 0
while mace_trans != 6:
    mace_trans = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(mace_trans)

    # Increment it every loop iteration
    num_rolls += 1

print(num_rolls)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built in method, but I do suggest you create some kind of counter variable and increment that each loop.

```
import random
mace_trans = 0
rounds = 0
while mace_trans != 6:
    rounds += 1
    mace_trans = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(mace_trans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

dice_roll = random.randint(1,6)
count = 0

while dice_roll != 6:
    count +=1
    dice_roll = random.randint(1,6)

if count == 0:
    print(f'{dice_roll} on the first roll !')
else:
    print(f'It took {count} dice rolls to get a 6.')
```